# Wamp server ip issue

Tags: wamp, wampserver

When I tried to access my localhost my IP like `192.168.1.7` then its working fine and show me all my project dir but when I try to access my project dir then IP turn to localhost so I can't access this address on different system. so how I can keep the IP same?

I have already tried some solution but it doesn't work.

I need to access my project like `http://192.168.1.7/myproject`

Comment: What do you mean “ip turn to localhost”?

Comment: When i try to access the url  http://192.168.1.7/myproject then its turn to http://localhost/myproject but i want to keep the same

Comment: Then fix your server or application to not do that. Without any knowledge of it, its configurations etc nobody can help you. It’s a problem specific to whatever you’ve done to it

Answer (score 1):

It seems your project has hard-coded code piece or website location is written in a configuration file.

**Here your check list can be to solve this issue:**

- Check your project files and search if any file consist localhost string anywhere
- Check .htaccess if it exists and see if there any localhost text

If you find any you can use *$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']* instead of hard-coded text. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will make it **dynamic** so it shouldn't be problem for you anymore.

Please give us more information about your project. We can't go further and help directly to your problem since we don't know so much details about it.